# Angular $watch not triggered on field modifed by popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular 1.4.x app that launches a popup window (for OAuth stuff). At some point that popup will write a value to an input field on the main parent window/app. That process works fine. What I would like is to then have the app run some code once that field is updated however it seems that when the field is updated by the popup the $watch function is never triggered. If I just put my cursor in the field and modify the value then it all works fine. What could be the issue?

The input field:

```
<input type="text" id="url" ng-model="item.url">
```

The controller watch bit:

```
$scope.$watch('item.url', function(n, o) {
  console.log(n, o);
});
```

The popup code that writes to parent:

```
var url = window.opener.document.getElementById("url").focus();
url.value = "hello";
```

Note that I don't really care if I use an input field - I am open to other methods. I just need to pass a value back to the angular app in a simple manner (i.e. some basic cross browser code without any libs) and have it go from there - this seems the most straightforward way.

Comment: That's normal because you're not using angular code to modify the value. That's why you have to manually trigger the digest loop by calling `scope.$apply`

Comment: Not sure I follow - how is me typing "using anguar code"? I can't trigger anything from the popup. is it a question of the window not being in focus?

Comment: For instance the ng-model value is known for angular. If you modify the value by getting the element and setting the value that way it's not known by angular. The digest loop isn't being triggerd. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
var opener = window.opener;

//Replace the 'controller-id' with the id of the controller div
var controllerDiv = opener.document.getElementById('controller-id');
var scope = opener.angular.element(controllerDiv).scope();

scope.title= 'Hello';
 //We update the scope manually, so we have to call this
scope.$digest();
```